# What is this date '1.5146712e+12' and how can I convert it to a proper format in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I must use an API that gives me dates of such format:

```
"date": 1.5146712e+12
"date": 1.5141528e+12
"date": 1.5146712e+12
```

What on earth is this?! And if it's valid thing how can I convert it to days, months and years?

Comment: Probably best to contact the owner of the API

Comment: `new Date(1.5146712e+12)` gives me `2017-12-30T22:00:00.000Z` but not sure this is correct. Best to contact the API owner.

Comment: It's likely a time value: `new Date(1.5146712e+12).toISOString()` gives "2017-12-30T22:00:00.000Z".

Comment: it's scientific format

Comment: It looks like any timestamp, with microseconds.

Comment: Probably just a value in *microseconds or something like that

Comment: @Magrangs Oh! Is it that much ununderstandable?

Comment: Is this part of a JSON string? If yes, which serializer/de-serializer are you using?

Comment: @RobG thanks Rob! I will take this for now.

Comment: @Matt good question! This is the API data out of the box. I get it using Postman. So it could be the serialiser in the API?

Comment: @ntalbs Sound right. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know what Postman is. If that is the name of the API, then its not a very famous one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It definitely looks like a [timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timestamp) number, which is a possible standard way of transmitting date/times.

A timestamp is a integer number representing, for instance, milliseconds or other units since a certain fixed date.

Just to clarify, 1.5146712e+12 means 1.5146712 * 10 to the 12th power, so it means 1'514'671'200'000.

This timestamp looks like milliseconds since 1st Jan 1970 00:00:00 000 UTC, more or less, guessed because this is **the standard timestamp that is used by the native Javascript Date**.

In this context, `1514671200000` should mean

> Sat Dec 30 2017 22:00:00 (UTC)

Note that this date/time is (supposedly) UTC.

(you can have a look at http://currentmillis.com)

To use this timestamp in JS, you can simply use `new Date(timestamp)`, which will create a javascript Date object from this timestamp.

Then, if you want a more readable format, you can use `.toISOString()` to get `2017-12-30T22:00:00.000Z` or `.toString()` with any date format you wish.

Also, for the reverse operation, note that the `Date.prototype.getTime()` JS function on a Date object will return the underlying timestamp.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation (educative)!